# Is there any method to change the value of input field in ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am getting default input fields values( which takes data from the API) and then updating some them an again posting the data to the back end by API.
But when i am sending the data to the Back end again only those values are appearing which are updated by me. The rest of values are showing null as they are not taking the default values.

Here is my code:

```
    export default function ReferralPayment() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const [member,setMember]=useState({ RefPerLVL1:"",RefPerLVL2:"",RefPerLVL3:"",RefPerLVL4:"",RefPerLVL5:"",RefPerLVL6:"",RefPerLVL7:"",RefPerLVL8:"",RefPerLVL9:"",RefPerLVL10:"",RefPerLVL11:"",RefPerLVL12:""
          })
     var name,value;
        const handleInputs=e=>{
          name=e.target.name;
          value=e.target.value;
          setMember({...member,[name]:value})
        }
     const postData=async (e)=>{
          const {RefPerLVL1,RefPerLVL2,RefPerLVL3,RefPerLVL4,RefPerLVL5,RefPerLVL6,RefPerLVL7,RefPerLVL8,RefPerLVL9,RefPerLVL10,RefPerLVL11,RefPerLVL12}=member;
         const res=await fetch("/refpaypost",{
           method:"POST",
           headers:{
             "Content-Type":"application/json"
           },
           body:JSON.stringify({
            RefPerLVL1,RefPerLVL2,RefPerLVL3,RefPerLVL4,RefPerLVL5,RefPerLVL6,RefPerLVL7,RefPerLVL8,RefPerLVL9,RefPerLVL10,RefPerLVL11,RefPerLVL12
           })
         });
         const data=await res.json();
            }
      useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchBooks() {
              const response = await fetch('/refpayget');
              const json = await response.json();
              setData(json.rf2);
              console.log(json.rf2)
          }
          fetchBooks();
         
      },[]);
       if (!data.length) {
        return null;
      }
     return (
 <table  style={{width:"80%",marginLeft:"20%"}}>
        <h4 style={{color:'black'}}>Referance Payments</h4>
       
        
          {  data.map((val,index)=>
          <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>LVL1</td>
          <td>{val. RefPerLVL1}%</td>
          <td> <Button variant="light" onClick={()=>{setShow(true);settext("LVL1 Payment Percentage");setname("RefPerLVL1")}}><Pencil size={20}/></Button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>LVL2</td>
            <td>{val.RefPerLVL2}%</td>
            <td> <Button variant="light" onClick={()=>{setShow(true);settext("LVL2 Payment Percentage");setname("RefPerLVL2")}}><Pencil size={20}/></Button></td>
                 
              </tr>
</tbody>
    )}         
      </table>
     <Form >
                  <Row >
                      <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">LVL1 Payment Percentage</Form.Text></Col>
                      <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="RefPerLVL1" placeholder="Enter Amount" autoFocus defaultValue={data[0].RefPerLVL1} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/></Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row >
                      <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">LVL2 Payment Percentage</Form.Text></Col>
                      <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="RefPerLVL2" placeholder="Enter Amount" defaultValue={data[0].RefPerLVL2} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/></Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row >
                    <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">LVL3 Payment Percentage</Form.Text></Col>
                      <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="RefPerLVL3" placeholder="Enter Amount" defaultValue={data[0].RefPerLVL3} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/></Col>
                  </Row>
    </Form>
     <Button variant="dark" onClick={()=>postData()}>
                    Save Changes
                  </Button>
```

If i didn't click on the input field, it doesn't changed and the value appear to be null as the `member usestate` have by default null values.
So how can I just use the default values of input fields when i didn't change the input fields?
If I try to initialise the `member usestate` with `data usestate`, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are more wanting fully controlled inputs over the uncontrolled inputs you currently have. The issue with using the `defaultValue` prop and not referencing the form when submitting is that the `member` state isn't updated until the `onChange` handler is triggered by.... *changing the input's value*. If the input is never changed then the updated value is never saved into state and used later.

To convert, first save your fetched "default" values into local state, and second, swap the `defaultValue` prop to the `value` prop so the inputs are controlled from the React state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchBooks() {
    const response = await fetch('/refpayget');
    const json = await response.json();
    setMember(json.rf2[0]); // <-- save the first array elements values
  }
  fetchBooks();
},[]);

...

<Form.Control
  size="sm"
  type="text"
  name="RefPerLVL1"
  placeholder="Enter Amount"
  autoFocus
  value={member.RefPerLVL1} // <-- switch to value prop, reference member state
  onChange={handleInputs}
/>
// ... repeat for other Form.Control inputs
```

Comment: There is a problem arises with this code. After clicking on "Save changes" button, the changes are not shown in the table, but when i reload the page then the changes are shown. If i put [data] inside the useeffect array, then it is not allowing to change the input field text. I want the changes to be shown in the table too after i click the save changes button. Is there any method for it?

Comment: @Beren Are you basically saying that you need to call `fetchBooks` again? What table are you referring to? Is this *some other* component? Does *it* need to be "notified" in some way to refetch some data?

Comment: Now i edited the code, before the form, there is a table which is mapping data from data usestate, but when i edit some table value using the form and click on save changes then the change value is not appearing in the table as the useeffect is called only once. Its the same component you can see the edited code. No it doesn't need to be notified . I just want the values in the table to be change after the form value is changed.

Comment: You can see further code here https://jsfiddle.net/gowm6s1t/

Comment: @Beren I don't see anything running in your fiddle, but I see that you are mapping the table values from the `data` state, but I don't see where you update the `data` state. Other than the mounting `useEffect` there's nothing else that updates the `data` state. It looks like you are/were trying to trigger the page to reload at the end of the `postData` handler though. Are you trying to reload the page so the mounting `useEffect` refetches the data?

Comment: Yes but i dont want the method of reloading the page it is not good, i just want after clicking on save changes the data send to the API and  if anything changes into the data API it will automatically fetch the API again. I am first updating the data on handleInput function at  "setMember({...member,[name]:value})" then i am pushing member usestate data to API using postData method. and after that i want to refetch the data. as in the backend the data changed

Comment: @Beren That's effectively what I asked if you are trying to do, update the `data` state after the POST request. If/when you update React state it will trigger a render with the new state. Is `const data=await res.json();` not the updated data you need? Does the POST response not return the updated data? If it isn't/doesn't, then you should add some other state to update so you can re-trigger the `useEffect` to call `fetchBooks` and make the GET request again and update the `data` state..